# How to resize jqgrid search box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

In my jqgrid the search box is small and text box is very small. I want to increase the size of search box(search window). I tried to use

```
searchoptions: {size: 30}
```

But I don't know where to put this code snippet. Can anyone see me example how can I increase the search box size using this or any other method.

Comment: read this: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

Comment: @bodi0 I can't see anything with search option or search box size in here..Can you please show some code example to how to do that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this and it worked.

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#gridPager',{add:false,edit:false,del:false,refresh: false},{},{},{},
              { 
                beforeShowSearch: function($form) {
                    $('#searchmodfbox_grid').width(760);
                    return true;
              }
              }
        );
```

In this search dialog's div id is { "searchmodfbox_" + yourGridId } . In my case my grid id is grid then search dialog's Id is "searchmodfbox_grid".

Comment: this is for jqgrid 4.4

Answer (score 0):

You can use beforeShowSearch (!!! not beforeshowsearch) to make changes in the searching dialog. See here for the code example (you can use this.id instead of grid[0].id if you use recent version of jqGrid). I recommend you to use recreateFilter: true searching option additionally.

By the way navGrid which add "Search" button to the navigator bar uses width property of prmSearch parameter on every call of searchGrid method which creates the grid. So if you would hold prmSearch and just change width the next search dialog will uses new width value:

```
var pSearch = {
        recreateFilter: true,
        multipleSearch:true,
        width: 500
    };

$("#list").jqGrid({...}); // create the grid

$("#list").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {}, {}, {}, {}, pSearch);
// if the user opens searching dialog now the width 500 will be used

...
pSearch.width = 800;
// if the user opens searching dialog now the new width 800 will be used
```